# Make a datepicker with angularjs (my views are not updated)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I wanted to create a datepicker using jqueryUi and angularjs. I want to get the datepicker value from all my controllers. For that, I created a factory :

```
App.factory "selectedDate", ['$rootScope', ($rootScope) ->
  selectedDates = {}
  selectedDates.from = moment()

  selectedDates.nextPeriod = ->
    this.from.add('days', 1);

  selectedDates.previousPeriod = ->
    this.from.subtract('days', 1);

  return selectedDates
]
```

And my controllers :

```
App.controller "DashboardDatePickerCtrl", ['$scope', 'selectedDate', ($scope,selectedDate) ->

  $scope.nextPeriod = () ->
    selectedDate.nextPeriod()

  $scope.previousPeriod = () ->
    selectedDate.previousPeriod()

  $scope.date = selectedDate.from
]

App.controller "otherCtrl", ['$scope', 'selectedDate', ($scope,selectedDate) ->
  $scope.date = selectedDate.from
]
```

My html (haml) :

```
.row-fluid{ "ng-controller" => "DashboardDatePickerCtrl" }
  .span4.offset5
    %span.fui-arrow-left.right10.top5.font-large.pointer{ "ng-click" => "previousPeriod()"}
    .control-group.inline
      .input-prepend.input-datepicker
        %button.btn{:type => "button"}
          %span.fui-calendar
        %input#datepicker-01.span2{:type => "text", "ng-model" =>"date", "datepicker" => ""}

    {{ date }}

    %span.fui-arrow-right.left10.font-large.pointer{ "ng-click" => "nextPeriod()"}

  .span3
    .btn-group.choose-granularity{"data-toggle" => "buttons-radio"}
      %button#by_4h.btn.btn-primary.one_month One month
      %button#by_1h.btn.btn-primary.one_week One week
      %button#by_5m.btn.btn-primary.one_day.active One day

.row-fluid
  .span12{ "ng-controller" => "otherCtrl" }
    %h6 An other ng controller
    %p
      {{ date.format("DD MMM, YYYY") }}
```

And to finish, my datepicker directive :

```
App.directive('datepicker', (selectedDate) ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
    require : 'ngModel'
    link : (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) ->
      $ ->
        element.datepicker({
          showOtherMonths: true
          selectOtherMonths: true
          dateFormat: "d MM, yy"
          yearRange: '-1:+1'
          onSelect: (date) ->
            selectedDate.from = moment(date)
            scope.$apply();
        })
    }
);
```

The fact is, when I select a date in my datepicker, the date on the "otherCtrl" or "DashboardDatePickerCtrl" does not change.

I thought that update the value of an attribute of my factory will update all other variables pointing to this variable.

What did I miss?

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/9HZdm/6/

Comment: could you set up a fiddle

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12576798/2013981) has the answers - also check at @Mark Rajcock's comment on the bottom answer.

Comment: I updated my question with the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you lose the reference to the `.from` property. As soon as your `otherController` and `DashboardDatePickerCtrl` starts, they get a reference to the `selectedDate.from`. But in your date change handler, you are changing the `.from` to another object in memory (`selectedDate.from = ...`), but the controllers are still pointing at the old one, now lost in memory for ever (quite dramatic).

The easy way to fix it, is to expose the entire selectedDate in the controller, and bind to its subproperty. This way, you will change the `.from`, but will not change the `.selectedDate`.

In your controller you should go with `$scope.date = selectedDate;` instead of `$scope.date = selectedDate.**from**` and in your bind, you should go as `date.from.format(...)`. This will solve the problem.

If you mind a suggestion, there is also [UI-Bootstrap calendar directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

I've talked a little about it at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14337338/179138).

Comment: Is it possible for you to update my fiddle? I try to apply what you are talking about but no success...Thx in advance

Comment: An one more question, how can I watch the change of "selectedDate" in my controllers from my directive "datepicker"?. When we click on next-period, I want to update my datepicker's input value.

Comment: This is a good question itself. I think it's good to discuss over it. But as you're changing the internal state of an object, and not the object reference itself, maybe the best choice is to not expose the `selectedDate.from` object, but instead only expose methods that would add (or subtract) values from the object and expose the result in some variable or dispatch an event that you would be able to listen to. I'll take some time to think about it, and will try to answer back. In the mean while, if you come up with a good approach, please let me know.