# AngularJS Controller wait for response (or set callback)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a AngularJS application with a controllers.js and factories.js.

What I like is to do something with the values in the controller (which I get from the factories). My problem is, that these values are empty at the time I access them.

How can I wait for the response? Or where can I add a callback?

```
    Flashcards.controller('CardDeckDetailController', function($scope, $routeParams, CardDeckService, CardService) {
    $scope.carddeck = CardDeckService.findCardDeckByID($routeParams.cardDeckID);
    $scope.cards = CardService.findCardsByCardDeckID($routeParams.cardDeckID);
    $scope.card = $scope.cards[0];
    $scope.cardLength = $scope.cards.length;

});

    Flashcards.factory('CardDeckService', function($resource) {
    var cardDeckService = $resource('/FlashcardsServer/rest/carddecks/:cardDeckID', {}, {});

    cardDeckService.findAllCardDecks = function() {
        return cardDeckService.query();
    };

    cardDeckService.findCardDeckByID = function(id) {
        return cardDeckService.get({ cardDeckID : id });
    };

    return cardDeckService;
});
```

What I like is to get the first car ($scope.cards[0]) and save it under $scope.card. But its always empty (same with cardsLength).

On the other hand if I print out the size from the partial view with (cards.length), I get the correct value.

Greets and Thanks
Marc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS: how to bind to promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033118/angular-js-how-to-bind-to-promises)

Comment: @lucama: with the $resource service it's a different problem

Comment: You can still return promises with a resource though it is a little different.  Here is an example: http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/ZXGdN3eRP2yabYILeDay?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get back the promise by accessing value.$then (has to go to the source code to find that):

```
Flashcards.controller('CardDeckDetailController', function($scope, $routeParams, CardDeckService, CardService) {
$scope.carddeck = CardDeckService.findCardDeckByID($routeParams.cardDeckID);
$scope.cards = CardService.findCardsByCardDeckID($routeParams.cardDeckID);
$scope.card =  $scope.cards.$then(function(){ return $scope.cards[0]; });
$scope.cardLength = $scope.cards.$then(function(){ return $scope.cards.length; });
```

edit: $then return the http response

Comment: Hi Guilllaume. Thanks for the idea. But that doesnt work. I get the message "Cannot call method '$then' of undefined"

Comment: Looks like you have a bug in your CardService then, it can't be undefined, $resource return an object and hydrate it when it has a response

Comment: Or you mispelled the property in the line you call $then

Comment: I have the following lines:
Service:
 cardDeckService.findAllCardDecks = function() {
  return cardDeckService.query();
 };
controller:
 $scope.carddecks = CardDeckService.findAllCardDecks();

 $scope.carddecks.$then(
  function(carddecks){ 
   alert('TET');
   return cards[0]; 
  }
 );

Without the $then part all the carddecks appear on the view without exception. Otherwise I get the message: "Object  has no method '$then'"...

Comment: Wich version of angularJS do you use? $then was commited recently (1.1.3)

Comment: Hi Guillaume. I used 1.0.5. With 1.1.4 it works better. But if i try to print out the object I dont get the card array I expected... the following gives me [object Object] but if i try to handle it like an array (return cards[0]) i get "undefined"...

 $scope.card = $scope.cards.$then(function(cards) {
  alert(cards);
  return cards[0];
 });

Comment: Ok I misread the source, try my edited code, hopefuly it will get the job done ;)

Comment: Great. It works now. What is the name in the function header for? I mean does it makes a difference if i put $then(function(xyz).. or $then(function(cards)... ? What is the object behind this? Or what can i use it for? :-)

Comment: the argument passed to the $then callback is the http response: The response object has these properties:
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request. Doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it's solving your problem

Comment: Thank you so much, Guillaume. You helped me a lot. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 3):

as lucuma suggests, this can probably be handled with a promise.
http://api.jquery.com/promise/ for the jquery promise
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q the angular promise is based on the jquery promise

this answer has a similar solution for multiple queries to complete
[AngularJS - wait for multiple resource queries to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299850/angularjs-wait-for-multiple-resource-queries-to-complete)

so instead of

```
cardDeckService.findCardDeckByID = function(id) {
    return cardDeckService.get({ cardDeckID : id });
};
```

use

```
cardDeckService.findCardDeckbyID = function(id){
   var d = $q.defer();
   var result = cardDeckService.get(id, function() {
        $scope.card = $scope.cards[0];
        d.resolve(result);
   });
   return d.promise;
}
```

in case you havent used promises, they are a better way to do "callbacks"

there is mention of $then in a github checkin, but i havent seen anything on the angular documentation site.  maybe it is now included to handle promises

Comment: Hi Anton. Thanks for your help. So how can I then access the result on the controller this way? I would like to implement the callback within the controller and pass it to the service as param.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past few days and I solved it this way:

```
cardDeckService.findCardDeckByID = function(id) {
        var toReturn = new Object();
        var something = cardDeckService.get({ cardDeckID : id }, function(){
            toReturn = something;
        });
        return toReturn;
    };
```

You first return an empty object (but NOT something that is "undefined"). When the DB call finishes AngularJS automagically updates the object `toReturn`. Also your view (if it is linked with the controller) will be updated.

The problem, doing your way, is that the `findCardDeckByID` returns an `undefined` value. So, `$scope.card` is undefined and it won't be automagically updated. Also your view, therefore, won't be updated.