# AngularJS controller performing a get times out

Tags: angularjs

I have a slight passing understanding of AngularJS but nothing more.  I have inherited a java app that is a mix between standard Spring MVC and AngularJS.  One of the AngularJS controllers calls a standard MVC controller to get a json data set.  When this controller takes too long the angularJS page errors out - presumably a timeout.

I have had a quick look around and it seems to me this is probably a design error and I should do this call further in the controller and use a $then call but I'd like to make as few changes as possible so I thought I'd see if there was a smaller change / better suggestion.

The controller, with the guts ripped out, is like this

```
'use strict'

var pageController = [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$location',
    '$window',
    '$filter',

    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter) {

        $.urlParam = function(name){
            ...
            return val;
         }

        $http
        .get(
            "/dataretrievalendpoint?searchparam=" + $.urlParam("searchparam"))
        .then(
                function(response) {
                    alert("All is well");
                    ....
                },
                function(response) {
                    alert("Error occurred !");
                }
               );
        }
    ];
```

So essentially if the .get("/dataretrievalendpoint...) takes too long (seems like milliseconds and on my laptop equates to about 2000 records) it goes to "Error occurred", otherwise "All is well".

Is there a way I can turn the .get into a future or extend the wait time ?  or do I need to investigate doing something along the lines of

```
$scope.param.$then = function(){ return make data retrieval call; }
```

([AngularJS Controller wait for response (or set callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239137/angularjs-controller-wait-for-response-or-set-callback))

Or should I be doing something else entirely ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$httpInterceptors` to extend the default $http timeout. Please check the below code.

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .config([ function() {

   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutHttpIntercept');

}])

.factory('timeoutHttpIntercept', [function () {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            config.timeout = 200000;
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here what we does is that we extend the default http timeout to 20 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: Hi we have a slightly different set up.  Should this work ?   Apologies will look at the docs properly myself tomorrow but thought I'd ask if it was obvious !      (app.js)       'use strict' var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngSanitize']).config([, function() {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutHttpIntercept');

 }]).factory('timeoutHttpIntercept', [function () {
     return {
         'request': function (config) {
             config.timeout = 200000;
             return config;
         }
     };
 }]);

Comment: @gringogordo: i have updated my code. Please take a look at it. Earlier i had put an unwanted "," i config. I have corrected it. Please remove the "," in .config([, function.. and try again. And yes, it should work.