# Present data from anonymous function in controller, angular

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller:

```
ProductsFactory.getOneProduct().then(function(d){
  $scope.selectedProduct = d.data;
  console.log($scope.selectedProduct); //Working
});
console.log($scope.selectedProduct); //Undefined
```

I can access the data from within the function. But not from outside. This means I cant use the data in my GUI. How do I make access from outside?

**Update**
Apperently it is working in the GUI. But you can not console anything outside.

Comment: XHR are asynchronous in nature therefore your second log executes before the first one.

Comment: Your request is asyn in nature, therefore you get undefined.

Comment: That's the way promises work. Your interface should gracefully treat the case when `$scope.selectedProduct` is `undefined`. After your async request executes and you update the `$scope` with new data Angular will know it needs to update the view also. It's been discussed in great detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033118/angular-js-how-to-bind-to-promises