# promises workflow in angular js, regarding pouchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, angular-promise, pouchdb

I'm trying to write some code in Angular js, it's my first time so there still are things I don't know.
I'm also using PouchDB, and following my logic I'd like to do:

- check is the DB has some stuff in it
- if yes, destroy it, and create a new one
- put new stuff in the DB

It seems pretty straightforward but probably I'm getting lost in the promises...

```
if (stuffInsideDB != undefined && stuffInsideDB !='')
{                       
    db.destroy().then(
        function(result)
        {
            db = new PouchDB('DB');
            db.info();                  
        }
    );
}
db.put(
    {
        _id: (currentIndex + 1).toString(),
        "data": encryptedHex.toString()
    }
).then(
    function() 
    { //do something}
);
```

Executing this code, it's executing the put before the destroy (and of course I'm getting an error). Is it because I'm not doing something like destroy().then(create().then(put())) ?

Many thanks

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033118/angular-js-how-to-bind-to-promises?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There may be number of solutions to this question. As you are interested in promises, here is a way to find out solution with promises:
**Note: I did not run this code locally, so you can take this as reference only.**

You can create a function to perform all the operations that you have mentioned in the question and return a promise from it, something like:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (stuffInsideDB != undefined && stuffInsideDB !=''){
        resolve(1);
    }else{
        reject();
    }

}).then(function (result) {
    return db.destroy();
}).then(function (result) {
        db.put(
            { _id: (currentIndex + 1).toString()
                ,"data": encryptedHex.toString()
            });
}).then(function (result) {
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Does it answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS it is important to wrap PouchDB promises in [`$q.when()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when). This will notify AngularJS to update the UI when the PouchDB promise has resolved.

The `.then` method of a promise returns a new promise that can be used for chaining actions. When [chaininig promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises), it is important to [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) values and promises to the handler function.

```
var promise = $q.when();

if (stuffInsideDB != undefined && stuffInsideDB !='')
{                       
    promise = db.destroy().then(
        function(result)
        {
            db = new PouchDB('DB');
            return db.info();                  
        }
    );
}

promise =  promise
 .then(function() {
   //IMPORTANT return the `db.put` promise
   return db.put(
    {
        _id: (currentIndex + 1).toString(),
        "data": encryptedHex.toString()
    }
).then(
    function() 
    { //do something}
);

return $q.when(promise);
```

The first part creates either an empty promise or a promise to destroy. The second part chains the `db.put` operation after that. The final part converts the ES6 promise to an AngularJS promise that is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service Promise API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).